# time.sleep in ipython extremely inaccurate

Tags: python, time, ipython, sleep

Doing some tests in an Ipython console, I noticed that `time.sleep()` was behaving strangely. I tried to clear all defined variables using `%reset -f`, and narrowed down the problem to those lines:

```
In [267]: %reset -f
     ...: import time
     ...: a = time.time()
     ...: time.sleep(0.0001)
     ...: print(f'took {time.time() - a}s')
took 3.1847519874572754s
```

Running the same code in a new Ipython console yields expected results:

```
In [1]: %reset -f
   ...: import time
   ...: a = time.time()
   ...: time.sleep(0.0001)
   ...: print(f'took {time.time() - a}s')
took 0.00023102760314941406s
```

I guess deleting all defined variables through `%reset -f` is not enough. I tried manually running the garbage collector through `import gc; gc.collect()` but it didn't change anything.

My guess is that ipython stores some things about the current session that I can't or don't know how to access but I couldn't find something useful. 
I'm using python 3.7.3, Ipython 7.10.1 in an iTerm2v terminal, on a MacOS 10.15.2.

Comment: Just for reference, your problem might actually be measurement: https://www.pythoncentral.io/measure-time-in-python-time-time-vs-time-clock/

Comment: Looks like you are right: using `%time time.sleep(0.01)`, I get a wall time of several seconds.. Loks like problem is not coming from Ipython but from scheduler. Thanks!